# Buenas, no puedo conectarme a ssh con public key en c#

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

tengo este codigo y no conecta

`SshClient cSSH = new SshClient("192.168.1.1", 22, "admin", "admin"); cSSH.Connect();`

instale el nuget de Renci.ssh.net el error que me tira es este: información adicional: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión.

en la imagen se ven los datos que me proporciona el router pero no entiendo donde ingresarlos. alguien si me puede orientar por favor, o alguna documentacion para leer